# Solution sets of $\cos(z)$ and $\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am looking for the following sets for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$

$$\{z: \cos(z)=0\} \text{ and } \{z: \sin(z)=0\}$$

I believe the best way to do this is consider the exponential form so

$$\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2} \text{ and } \sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

So for $\cos(z)=0$ we have

$$e^{iz}=-e^{-iz}$$

and for $\sin(z)=0$ we have

$$e^{iz}=e^{-iz}$$

Since $\sin$ and $\cos$ are defined from their real power expansion I know $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$ will do it respectively for example but I am having trouble getting my head around working with the solutions in general. To consider the $\cos(z)$ case we have

$$e^{iz}=-e^{-iz}$$

$$e^{ix}e^{-y}=-e^{-ix}e^{y}$$

So do we want $e^{-y}=e^y$ since those would be the moduli respectively and $ix=-ix+2 \pi k$ since that gives the argument of my numbers? I am struggling with both cases so a few hints and a general strategy would be greatly appreciated.

## My solutions:

We consider the exponential expression of $\cos(z)$. We have

\begin{align*} \cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}&=0\\
        e^{iz}&=-e^{-iz}\\
        e^{2iz}&=-1\\
        e^{i2x}e^{-y}&=-1
       \end{align*}

Which implies $y=0$ and $2x=\pi +2\pi k$. We have $x=\frac{\pi}{2} +\pi k$.

We consider the exponential expression of $\sin(z)$. We have

\begin{align*}
        \sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2}&=0\\
        e^{iz}&=e^{-iz}\\
        e^{2iz}&=1\\
        e^{i2x}e^{-y}&=1
       \end{align*}

Which implies $y=0$ and $2x=2\pi k$. We have $x=\pi k$.

Let me know if everything went down the way it should have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You believe correctly, but you can do some more algebra. For the zero set of the sine you have to solve
$$
e^{iz}-e^{-iz}=0
$$
that is
$$
e^{2iz}=1
$$
If you set $z=x+iy$ you get
$$
e^{-2y}e^{2ix}=1(\cos 0+i\sin 0)
$$
which means $y=0$ and
$$
2x=2k\pi
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** Note that the equation $e^{iz} = -e^{-iz}$ that arises in the cosine case is equivalent to $e^{2 i z} = -1$. One solution is $z = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so the solution set is that of $$2 i z - 2 i \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = 2 \pi ik,$$ $k \in \Bbb Z$.

Alternatively, one can use the formula $$\cos (x + iy) = \cos x \cosh y - i \sin x \sinh y$$
giving the real and imaginary parts of $\cos z$ in terms of those of the components $x, y$ of $z$; there is an analogous equation for $\sin z$.